# how to get multiple text with same name?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

when checkbox are checked for each checkbox jquery create input
How can I get all inputs with name??

if checkbox checked create input:

```
    <script>
function dynInput(cbox) {
    if (cbox.checked) {
        var input = document.createElement("input");
        input.type = "text";
        input.className = "cbox";
        var div = document.createElement("div");
        div.className = "cbox-div";
        div.id =  cbox.name;
        div.innerHTML =cbox.name;

        div.appendChild(input);
        document.getElementById("insertinputs").appendChild(div);
    } else {
        document.getElementById(cbox.name).remove();
    }
}</script>
```

checkbox and Inputs:

```
      <form class="add-item">
          <input type="checkbox"  onclick="dynInput(this);"  name="1"> 1<br>
          <input type="checkbox"  onclick="dynInput(this);"  name="2"> 2<br>
          <input type="checkbox"  onclick="dynInput(this);"  name="3"> 3<br>
          <input type="checkbox"  onclick="dynInput(this);"  name="4"> 4<br>
      </form>
      <p id="insertinputs"></p>
```

I can only get first Input value :

```
    var item = $(".cbox").val();

    console.log(item);
```

Comment: because as the documentation states for val() it only returns the first item in the collection. You would need to loop over the collection and read each item's value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to iterate over all the inputs like:

```
$(".cbox").each(function(){
    var item = $(this).val();
    console.log(item);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var item=[];
$(".cbox").each(function(){
item.push($(this).val());
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var items = document.querySelectorAll('.cbox');

var values = [];

items.forEach(function(item) {
  values.push(item.value);
});

console.log(values);
```

Answer (score 0):

because as the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/val/) states for val() it only returns the first item in the collection. You would need to loop over the collection and read each item's value.

So you need to loop over the collection and build up the list. You can do it with each() or map()

```js
var vals1 = [];
$('[type="checkbox"]').each( function () {
   vals1.push(this.value);
});

var vals2 = $('[type="checkbox"]').map( function () {
   return this.value;
}).get();

console.log("vals1", vals1.join(","))
console.log("vals2", vals2.join(","))
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" value="a"> 1<br>
<input type="checkbox" value="b"> 2<br>
```